# How to repeatedly add characters to a String Java

Tags: java

For homework, I got a question that wants me to print the characters of a string in a staircase fashion.

```
//so if String str = "Compute", I should end up with
C
 o
  m
   p
    u
     t
      e
```

This is my work so far.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x = 0;

    String str = "Compile";

    for (int z=0;z<str.length();z++) {
        char ans = str.charAt(x);
        String inn=" "+ans
        System.out.println(inn);
        x++;
    }
}
```

I really don't know where to go from here. Please help me.

Comment: I think your question needs to be a little more specific, simply stating the problem and a blob of code with 'i'm stuck' isn't the way you're likely to get answers here. Your piece of code is a good attempt, you've nearly got it right (good job!). It is much more desirable to state what specifically you're stuck at or what specifically your code cannot do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a loop to print `z` spaces before each character at `z`. Something like,

```
String str = "Compile";
for (int z = 0; z < str.length(); z++) {
    char ans = str.charAt(z);
    for (int x = 0; x < z; x++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.println(ans);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
String str = "Compile";
String spaces = "";
for (int z = 0; z < str.length(); z++) {
    char ans = str.charAt(x);
    System.out.println(spaces + str.charAt(z));
    spaces += " ";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to print as many spaces as your current letter count, this should work now:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x = 0;

    String str = "Compile";

    for (int z = 0; z < str.length(); z++) {
        char ans = str.charAt(x);
        for (int i = 0; i < x; ++i)
            System.out.print(' ');
        System.out.println(ans);
        x++;
    }
}
```

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < x; ++x)` isn't right. Infinite loop when `x` is greater than `0` (because `i` doesn't change).

Comment: How is `x` different to `z` ?